# ORACLE directory premissions for external tables

Tags: oracle, permissions, directory, external

I have a oracle external table. There is a oracle directory created for use of external table to read input CSV file. DISCARD, LOG and BAD files of external table will be created in the same directory.

When corresponding directory on unix has permissions "1770", external table can not read or write from that directory. When permissions for that directory are changed to "1777", external table is able to read write into that directory.

I am not able to figure out what is the issue when permissions for that directory are 1770. Please provide me with any hint on this weird behavior.

Please note that oracle schema user has READ and WRITE grants on that directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What user and group owns the operating system directory?  What operating system user runs the Oracle database?  What group(s) is that operating system user that runs Oracle in?

It sounds from your description that the operating system user that runs Oracle does not own the operating system directory and is not part of the group that owns the directory.  In Unix, privileges on a directory are granted to the user (the first 7), the group (the second 7), and to the public (the third digit, either a 7 or a 0 in your example).  If changing the privileges associated with the public are changing the behavior, that implies that the Oracle operating system user only has the privileges granted to the public on this directory.

Comment: Thanks Justin for the explanation. In my case situation was the user who is executing the code and user who started the ORACLE did not belong to same group. Thanks again.